# supplying user defined color in r circlize package

Tags: r, plot, geometry, circlize

I am trying create circle diagram using circlize package in R.

Here example where I use random color:

```
require(circlize)

circos.par("default.track.height" = 0.1, cell.padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
circos.initializeWithIdeogram(plotType = NULL)

bed1 = generateRandomBed(nr = 10)

f = colorRamp2(breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), colors = c("green", "black", "red"))

rand_col = function(k) {
    return(rgb(runif(k), runif(k), runif(k)))
}

circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion(bed1, stack = FALSE,  numeric.column=4, panel.fun = function(region,  value, ...) {
    circos.genomicRect(region, value, col = rand_col(nrow(region)), border = NA, ...)
})
```

Will lead to figure like this:

[image]

Now I would like to pass own colors - not random as generated in previous case.

```
bed1$clr <- sample(c("red", "green", "blue", "purple", "red",
              "yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "cyan"), nrow(bed1), replace=TRUE)

circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion(bed1, stack = FALSE,  numeric.column=4, panel.fun = function(region,  value,  ...) {
    circos.genomicRect(region, value, col = bed1$clr, border = NA, ...)
})
```

But hit error:

```
Error in .normalizeGraphicalParam(col, 1, nr, "col") : 
  The length of `col` (19) should be equal to 1 or the number of your regions (1).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `panel.fun`, `region` and `value` correspond to the data on each chromosome, so you cannot use `bed1$clr` because `bed1$clr` corresponds to the whole data.

actually, in `panel.fun`, `value` contains columns excluding the first three columns in `bed1` and only contains data for the current chromosome (remember `panel.fun` applied on each chromosome), so you can change your code to:

```
circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion(bed1, panel.fun = function(region,  value,  ...) {
    circos.genomicRect(region, value, col = value$clr, border = NA, ...)
})
```

BTW, replace `default.track.height` to `track.height` in `circos.par` if you are using the latest version of `circlize` (0.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column in which each row is associated with one color or different values ​​in the same color.
For example, you can create a empty vector, and the use of a loop that parses all your data.frame. In this case, when the loop finds a value == 1, it adds the color "black" to the vector, when finds a value == 2, it adds the colour "red",and so on.

```
vector <- c()
for(i in seq(nrow(test))){
  if (test$Color[i] == 1){
  vector <- c(vector, "black")}
  if (test$Color[i] == 2){
  vector <- c(vector, "red")}
}
```

After, you can add the column in your original data.frame like this:

```
test["paint"] <- vector
```

To end, you can add in the border option, the column with your selected colours.

```
circos.par("track.height" = 0.1, cell.padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
circos.initializeWithIdeogram(chromosome.index = chrom)
bed = test
circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion(test, panel.fun = function(region, value, ...) {
circos.genomicRect(region, value, border = bed$paint)
})
```